# Duda para mostrar datos en c# desde un sp en oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedure

Buenas tardes tengo una duda relacionada a c# y oracle, bueno tengo varios procedimientos almacenados en una base de datos Oracle (Oracle 11G) en varios de estos algunos con parámetros de entrada y otros que solo muestran todo (select * From nombre), mi duda es como capto el sp de oracle y muestro todos sus datos en c#,ya que de la forma que hago me aparece el error de "**wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SPLISTARCLIENTES'** " les daré alguno de los ejemplos que tengo.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SPLISTARCLIENTES
(pruebaRecords OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)AS 
BEGIN
  OPEN pruebaRecords FOR
      SELECT * 
      FROM CLIENTE;      
END SPLISTARCLIENTES;
```

y el codigo de c# (los label solo los tengo para comprobar si trae datos o no)

```
 OracleConnection cnn = new OracleConnection("Data Source = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = xe))); User Id = xxxxxx; Password = xxxxxx; Pooling = true; Max Pool Size = 10; Min Pool Size = 1");
            string sql = "SPLISTARCLIENTES";
            OracleConnection cn = cnn;

            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql,cn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                                   try
            {
                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteReader();


                OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(reader[0]);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Label2.Text = Convert.ToString(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                cn.Close();
                cmd.Dispose();
                cn.Dispose();
            }
```

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debes especificar el parámetro sysrefcursor de la siguiente manera

```
OracleParameter p_rc = cmd.Parameters.Add("pruebaRecords ",
    OracleDbType.RefCursor,
    DBNull.Value,
    ParameterDirection.Output);
```

Comment: Acabo de probarlo como dijiste y me ha funcionado a la perfección, muchísimas gracias.